# Stuck on Javascript slideshow

Tags: javascript

All I got from this prompt is I need to is name the page talent.html, then have some kind of box pop up but alert only recognize string, then use setInterval for the timer and have an array of images, any help figuring out what's supposed to be done here would be appreciated.

Code a web page using Javascript named talent.html, and create a link to it from your home page. Use your imagination to design and code a web page that includes the  features listed below - CODE THIS JAVASCRIPT - NOT JQUERY!  WRITE THE CODE  Use these techniques:
WHen the page first displays, it displaysan alert box with a greeting. It contains a picture and a button labeled "start the show"
When the button is clicked, it will  display a slideshow of 5 pictures that automatically rotate every 2 seconds.
(hint, use a timer)

```
<script>
function startShow(){
    window.setInterval("changeImage()", 2000);
}

function changeImage()
{   
var imgSrcs = new Array(5);
    imgSrcs[0] = new Image()
    imgSrcs[0].src = "Images/dog1.jpg";
    imgSrcs[1] = new Image()
    imgSrcs[1].src = "Images/dog2.jpg";
    imgSrcs[2] = new Image()
    imgSrcs[2].src = "Images/dog3.jpg";
    imgSrcs[3] = new Image()
    imgSrcs[3].src = "Images/dog4.jpg";
    imgSrcs[4] = new Image()
    imgSrcs[4].src = "Images/dog5.jpg";
var i = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3));
var element = document.getElementById("slideShow");
element.src= imgSrcs[i];
}
</script>
</head>

<body onLoad="startShow">

<p><img src="Images/dog1.jpg" alt="Dogs" id="slideShow"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: code ? what have you tried so far

Comment: Tried to get a timer slide show at least then figure out the box thingy

Comment: Please try to find a new source how to learn JavaScript. That code looks like it was written in 1998.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is you are missing `()` for the attribute `onload`:

```
<body onLoad="startShow">
```

Try this example:

```js
function startShow() {
  window.setInterval(changeImage, 2000);
}

var imgSrcs = []; //create only once
imgSrcs.push('http://simpleicon.com/wp-content/uploads/light-bulb-14.png');
imgSrcs.push('http://www.innovateli.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/bulb.png');
imgSrcs.push('http://images.clipartpanda.com/lightbulb-icon-lightbulb_shine-128.png');
imgSrcs.push('https://enterprise.cloudshark.org/www/img/iconmonstr-light-bulb-17-icon.svg');

function changeImage() {
  var i = Math.floor((Math.random() * imgSrcs.length));
  document.getElementById("slideShow").src = imgSrcs[i];
}
```

```html
<body onLoad="startShow();">
  <p>
    <img src="http://simpleicon.com/wp-content/uploads/light-bulb-14.png" alt="Bulbs" id="slideShow" width="100">
  </p>
</body>
```